# Mixed mode assembly is built, after upgrade to windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, windows-10

I use small aplication, it works fine on windows 8.1, after I upgrade to windows 10 after run application I get Unhandled exception

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

Can I do something with it, without re-compile? I no longer have the source code. Maybe edit MSIL, SetUp old runtime...??

Thanks for help

Comment: Hmm, no, that has not changed.  You need to create [a .config file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5883258/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need recompile app. Should suffice add yourapp.exe.config to same folder with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

or add to existing config.

if that does not work and you do not have source code, you can decompile app to IL code by

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools>ildasm.exe D:\Temp\yourapp.exe /output:D:\Temp\yourapp\yourapp.il
```

repair runtime version in IL and then compile it

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>ilasm.exe D:\Temp\yourapp\yourapp.il /output:D:\Temp\yourappPatch.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is about Windows 8.x still accepts .Net Framework 2.0 compatibility (for ASP purposes, I guess) but Windows 10 refuses it.

I guess you won´t have any solution unless you MUST recompile your app adding the Reference Library and setting up to be put in your application folder.